# Spring - Return String or JSONObject into JSONP

Tags: java, json, spring, jsonp

I am able to return a JSONP from a custom java object without problems (following this: http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-jsonp-example-with-rest-responsebody-responseentity), but when i try to return a String withing the JSONP the wrapping function disappears

What i am doing:

```
  @RequestMapping(value ="/book", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/javascript"})
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> bookInfo() {
    JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
    test.put("uno", "uno");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(test.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Call to the service:

```
http://<server>:port//book?callback=test
```

Returns:

```
{"uno":"uno"}
```

Expected result:

```
test({"uno":"uno"})
```

Also tried to return directly the JSONObject `ResponseEntity.accepted().body(test);` but i got a 406 Error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like the class `JsonpAdvice` from [this example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-jsonp-example-with-rest-responsebody-responseentity),  isn't available for the request mapping.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

I used HashMap, since it has a similar use here and HashMap is more straightforward to use in this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/book", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<Map> bookInfo() {
    Map test = new HashMap();
    test.put("uno", "uno");
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(test);
}
```

This provided me with the result:

```
// http://localhost:8080/book?callback=test

/**/test({
  "uno": "uno"
});
```

I was using Spring boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I tried, but when i return the JSONObject the response is a 406 error code

Comment: I got the same error when I didn't have the `JsonpAdvice` class in my class path. Once I did I started to get 500 errors, because I didn't configure Spring to serialize JSONObject. So I switched to HashMap, which is easily converted to Json. The example specifically declares the type. I'll update my answer to contain this.

Comment: Thanks, actually switch to the HashMap was the way i used it, i re search a little more and realize the JSONObject cannot serialize just as you mention, thanks!